# Will Prince of Persia 3D run on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, system-requirements, prince-of-persia-3d

According to [its system requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_3D), the game says it needs Windows 98 or Windows ME.

Can I play it if I have Windows 7 instead? Or do I need an older OS to be able to run it?

Comment: Have you tried running it in Windows 98/Windows Me compatibility mode?

Comment: no, how does that work?

Comment: I agree with James Jiao, compatibility mode is your best bet. In control panel, search for compatibility in the top right hand corner and its the only search result that shows up.

Comment: Win98 era games are iffy on Win7.  IIRC, they didn't even work well or at all on XP.  You'll probably have to grab an old box and install Win98 on it if you want to play it.

Comment: Another option is to run VMWare, but this might be a little too advanced for you.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to at least run on Win7, but at least on the 64-bit version, is laggy. Here's a video that shows this:

Comment: Mark, thanks for the embed. I should figure out how to do that sometime.

Answer (score 2):

Run Dosbox (http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1) and play any DOS Game under any Windows version

Comment: Yeah, except Prince of Persia 3D is *NOT* a DOS game.